# Pylint cannot detect mistyped member function name of a class instance

Tags: python, pylint

when i pass class instances as a parameter of some functions,Pylint cannot detect "Class has no such member Error( like: E1101 )"

```
class HelloClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__message: str = "hello"
    def say_hello(self) -> None:
        print(self.__message)

def run(hello_instance: HelloClass) -> None:
    hello_instance.say_hello()
    hello_instance.say_blah_blah()  # Not detected as error by pylint

my_hello_instance: HelloClass = HelloClass()
my_hello_instance.say_blah_blah() # Detected as error by pylint
run(my_hello_instance) # Runtime error
```

in the sample codes above, Pylint ignores mistyped class function name say_blah_blah() in run()

is it related to the dynamic language feature of python?

can i force this can be checked by some pylint configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pylint ignores mistyped class function cause in Python you can add it dinamically anywhere in code.
You can use MyPy (`pip install mypy`) for static typecheck. It will show you `"HelloClass" has no attribute "say_blah_blah"` message in such a case.